# Publicly accessible IP for Vagrant on OSX

Tags: macos, ubuntu, network-programming, vagrant, netcat

Trying to learn a bit more about networking via Vagrant and Linux.

My machine is running OSX and I've spun up a Vagrant box (trusty 64) and set up a simple `netcat` redirect like so:

`printf 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved\r\nLocation: https://www.eff.org/' | nc -l 2345`

I'm trying to get `netcat` to redirect my browser when I hit it (IP:2345) but nothing seems to work. I've tried looking up the IP from Vagrant a bunch of times and I keep finding different addresses and none of them work. Browser simply hangs and `netcat` never receives the request.

I've very little experience in VMs so I'm guessing that there isn't a publicly accessible IP in this instance? At least not with some config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to bridge the network. Add this to the `Vagrantfile`:

`Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network"
end`

Documentation on this here:
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html